# flags enum bitwise operator not working as expected

Tags: c#

I'm using C# 3.5 for a mobile app on Windows Mobile 6.5 and i've been using this simple code forever but it suddenly stopped working:

```
//Regroup the issues
ScanIssuesEnum NewIssues = 0;
NewIssues |= Direction1Issues;
NewIssues |= Direction2Issues;

//Remove invalid directions because we don't care about them in bidirectionnal mode
NewIssues ^= ScanIssuesEnum.InvalidDirectionIssue;
return NewIssues;
```

I checked thoroughly all my types just to make sure i wasn't using another type, everything is based off the same ScanIssuesEnum type and the type is [Flag]'ed as you can see below:

```
[Flags] public enum ScanIssuesEnum
{
    TicketUsedTooSoonIssue = 1,
    TicketUsedTooLateIssue = 2,
    TicketUsageBustedIssue = 4,
    InvalidTripIssue = 8,
    InvalidDirectionIssue = 16,
    StartStopTooSoonIssue = 32,
    StartStopNotFoundIssue = 64,
    EndStopTooLateIssue = 128,
    EndStopNotFoundIssue = 256,
    MultipleUsageSameTripIssue = 512,
    MultipleUsageInFewHoursIssue = 1024,
    StudentTicketIssue = 2048,
    ConnectingTripWithinTimeframeFlag = 4096,
    UDESStudentTicketIssue = 8192,
}
```

In my current problem, i can see EndStopNotFoundIssue in both DirectionIssues, when combined into NewIssues, i get a value that contains two times EndStopNotFoundIssue. I thought it wouldn't really matter until i return the value, maybe it's just a visual IDE bug but no, the problem persists. Even worst, when i hit the line that removes the InvalidDirectionIssue flag, it adds it to the NewIssues...

Am i crazy? ^= is the equivalent of x = x ^ y no? So i should remove the flag, not add it right?

Thanks

**Edit #1 - Values of the DirectionIssues**

As requested by Wonko the sane, the values of Direction1Issue and Direction2Issue are both EndStopNotFoundIssue or 256.

After the line "NewIssues ^= ScanIssuesEnum.InvalidDirectionIssue;" my NewIssues is composed of "EndStopNotFoundIssue  | EndStopNotFoundIssue  | InvalidDirectionIssue". And obviously it shouldn't!

**Edit #2 - Values of DirectionIssues wrongly read**

Ha, the two DirectionIssues had different values, i was just reading them incorrectly. In fact it was EndStopNotFoundIssue and EndStopTooLateIssue. Damn mind not read the whole words hehe. So the OR portion was fine, it was my brain playing tricks on me.

I changed the problematic portion about the InvalidDirectionIssue that i'm trying to XOR out using the "x = x & ~y" form and it works, dunno why it works while the "x ^= y" doesn't but hell! Solution found!

Comment: For the heck of it, what are the actual (int) values of Direction*Issues?

Comment: @WonkotheSane Edited the post with the values

Comment: Hmmm...a quick console app (.NET 4.0) seems to show it working as expected.  I got 272 (InvalidDirectionIssue, EndStopNotFoundIssue) running the code above.  I created new ScanIssuesEnum variables to hold the DirectionIssues values and set the explicitly to ScanIssuesEnum.EndStopNotFoundIssue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several things that might help you.

- ^ is exclusive-or, so it switches/toggles the bits that you apply, it does not clear them. So if the `EndStopNotFoundIssue` value is not set, then using ^ will set it, not clear it. If you want to clear a value, use `x &= ~y` (AND x with the inverted bits of y).
- `EndStopNotFoundIssue | EndStopNotFoundIssue` equals `EndStopNotFoundIssue`. ORing a value with itself just returns the same value. So you're not telling us something. Are you using a `+` rather than an `|` or something? Are the values of the variables you're ORing in really what you think they are? Have you single stepped through the code in your debugger to see what the values are at every stage? You need to post more of your code for us to work out where it's gone wrong.
- You're using values that do not appear to have come from your enum (0 and Direction1Issues for example). So we can't read your code to work out what might be going wrong as we have no idea what Direction1Issues is set to. And it's generally a bad idea to mix different types. 0 is an integer, but you are setting it into an enumerated type. Define a constant like `None=0` to make your code more readable and more type-safe.
- For your constants, try using the style below - it's much easier to see which bit you are setting, know that you are only setting one bit, and be sure that you calculate the next value correctly when you add a new item:

  ```
  public enum ScanIssuesEnum
  {
      TicketUsedTooSoonIssue = 1<<0,
      TicketUsedTooLateIssue = 1<<1,
      TicketUsageBustedIssue = 1<<2,
      InvalidTripIssue       = 1<<3,
      InvalidDirectionIssue  = 1<<4,
      ...
  ```

Comment: I changed the problematic portion about the InvalidDirectionIssue that i'm trying to XOR out using the "x = x & ~y" form and it works, dunno why it works while the "x ^= y" doesn't but hell! Solution found!

Comment: `OR 1` sets a bit (forces it to be a 1). `XOR 1` inverts the value of the bit (so if you keep XORing with the same value, it turns on and off and on and off - half the time it is setting rather than clearing it). `AND 1` allows you to preserve a bit's value. To clear a bit you need to do an `AND 0` on that bit - or to look at it another way, you need to preserve all the bits _except_ the one you want to affect - so you AND with the NEGATED value by using & and ~ together.

Comment: Oh, i tought XOR cleared the bit in all cases, thanks, that clears up the problem...

Answer (score 0):

`x ^= y` is the equivalent of `x = x ^ y`.  That means it toggles the state existence of y in a flags enum.  It can be used to set or unset.